# Displaying outline of municipalities where wind turbines are located

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

With this query, I get the outline of the department of Yonne in France and the points representing the wind turbines.

I would also like to obtain the outline of the municipalities where the wind turbines are located.

```
[out:json];
area["ref:INSEE"="89"]->.a;
rel(area.a)["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="6"];
out geom;
node(area.a)["power"="generator"]["generator:source"="wind"];
out geom;
```

This is an example:

[image: outline of the municipalities]

How can I modify the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution :

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area["ref:INSEE"="89"]->.a;
rel(area.a)["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="6"];
out geom;
node(area.a)["power"="generator"]["generator:source"="wind"]["generator:method"="wind_turbine"]["generator:output:electricity"];
out geom;
node(area.a)["power"="generator"]["generator:source"="wind"]["generator:method"="wind_turbine"]["generator:output:electricity"]->.b;
.b is_in->.c;
rel(pivot.c)["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="8"];
out geom;
{{style:
node {width: 0;opacity:0;fill-opacity:0;}
node[power=generator] { icon-image: url("icons/maki/cross-18.png"); icon-width: 12;}
}}
```

[image: Parc_eolien_outline]